# how to remove plot elements in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to a 3d figure without any plot elements in python. Sort of a 3d version of [this](http://print%28ax.frameo%29).

When I run the code I have added below, I get regular plot[image: a figure of (Very) simplified surface]. 
I want to remove the axes, axes labels, ticks, and background (and remain only with the surface).

How can I remove them.

Also, is there  way to add arrows to the plot?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import math

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pi = 3.14159
bignum = 3
amp = 0.1

mat = []
X = []
Y = []
class mode:
    i=0
    j=0
    phase=0
    amp=0
modes = dict() 
for i in range(0,3):
    submodes = dict()
    for j in range (0,5):
        if not (i==0 and j==2):
            m = mode()
            m.i = i
            m.j = j
            m.amp = amp*random.random()/(pow(i,2) + pow(j-2,2))
            m.phase = random.random()*2*pi
            submodes[j] = m
            modes[i] = submodes

for x in range (0,bignum): 
    mat.append([])
    for y in range (0,bignum):
        dz = 0
        for i in range (0,3):
            for j in range (0,5):
                if not (i == 0 and j == 2):
                    dz += math.cos(i*x*2*pi/bignum + j *y*2/bignum + modes[i][j].phase)*modes[i][j].amp
        mat[x].append(dz)

X = np.mgrid[:bignum,:bignum]
print (len(X[0]))
print (len(mat))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(2.))
fig.frameon=True

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.frameon=False
ax.xticks=[]
ax.yticks=[]
ax.zticks=[]
surf = ax.plot_surface(X[0],X[1],mat,rstride=1, cstride=1,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not that this is off topic here (because it isn't), but this kind of question would also fit on [scicomp.SE], and it'd benefit from an audience more dedicated to scientific computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the 3d frame from  the figure, use:

```
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

Comment: add this and you get a totally gray background `plt.setp(ax.get_frame(), visible = False)`.  At the very least you should use ndarrays instead of dict, vectorization takes time to learn for sure but can save you on large data sets

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer much of your question.  But you can start turning stuff off with

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

I did some of it below.  Also, the plt.annotate() function is how to add arrows in 2d plots...not sure how it upscales.

```
import random
import math

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pi = 3.14159
bignum = 3
amp = 0.1

mat = []
X = []
Y = []
class mode:
    i=0
    j=0
    phase=0
    amp=0
modes = dict() 
for i in range(0,3):
    submodes = dict()
    for j in range (0,5):
        if not (i==0 and j==2):
            m = mode()
            m.i = i
            m.j = j
            m.amp = amp*random.random()/(pow(i,2) + pow(j-2,2))
            m.phase = random.random()*2*pi
            submodes[j] = m
            modes[i] = submodes

for x in range (0,bignum): 
    mat.append([])
    for y in range (0,bignum):
        dz = 0
        for i in range (0,3):
            for j in range (0,5):
                if not (i == 0 and j == 2):
                    dz += math.cos(i*x*2*pi/bignum + j *y*2/bignum + modes[i][j].phase)*modes[i][j].amp
        mat[x].append(dz)

X = np.mgrid[:bignum,:bignum]
print (len(X[0]))
print (len(mat))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(2.))
fig.frameon=True

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.frameon=False

surf = ax.plot_surface(X[0],X[1],mat,rstride=1, cstride=1,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_zticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_zticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax.get_frame(), visible = False)
#plt.annotate(r'Hello', xy = (.5, .5),
#                xytext = (10,10),
#                textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',
#                                                connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'))

plt.show()
```

You didn't ask this...but you should vectorize this code.  Most/(all?) of the for loops could be avoided.

Comment: Thanks. I know I should avoid loops but I can't see how I can escape them here. Mainly the power of i and j.